# Struts Database Login

Tags: java, database, jsp, authentication, struts2

I have a struts web application that implements login page from a database.  I can't seem to get it to properly pull the username and password correctly from the database from my login form. I'm trying to use annotations in place of struts xml to redirect my pages.  I do get ERROR result but can't get SUCCESS result to work.  Just need some pointers on what I'm doing wrong to get it to properly work.

Login.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="/template/header.jsp" />
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<title>Login</title>

<div id="loginsection">
<h2>Login in your account&nbsp<img src="images/padlock.png"
alt="padlocklogo" height="40" width="50"></h2>

<div id="loginform">
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="loginaction" method="post" >
    <s:textfield label="Username" name="username" class="username"/><p></p>
    <s:password label="Password" name="password" cssClass="passwordfield"/>
   <s:submit value="Login" class="submitbutton"/>
</s:form>
</div><br><br><br>


<div id="loginbuttons">
<p>Forgot Password</p><a href="help.jsp" class="helpbutton">Help</a>
<br><br>
<p>Need to Register?</p><a href="register.jsp"   
class="registerbutton">Register</a>
<br><br>
</div>
</div>

<jsp:include page="/template/footer.jsp" />
```

Login Action:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String username;
private String password;
private String userid;
private String userpwd;
Connection conn = null;


public void setUsername(String username) {
     this.username = username;
}
public String getUsername() {
     return username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


@Action(value="loginaction", results={
        @Result(name="success", location="/welcome.jsp"),
        @Result(name="error", location="/login.jsp")})
public String execute() {
  String usr = "admin";
  String pwd = "pwd123";
  String ret = ERROR;

  try {
     String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
     OracleDriver driver = new OracleDriver();
     DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pwd);
     String sql = "SELECT username,password FROM usermanagement WHERE";
     sql+=" username = ? AND password = ?";
     PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pstmt.setString(1, username);
     pstmt.setString(2, password);
     ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

     while (rs.next()) {
         userid = rs.getString(1); 
         userpwd = rs.getString(2); 
         if (username.equals(userid) && password.equals(userpwd))
         ret = SUCCESS; 
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
          addActionError("Invalid Username/Password"); 
       ret = ERROR;
   } finally {
      if (conn != null) {
         try {
            conn.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you print the exception (e.printStacktrace()) and check what the actual exception is ? ERROR is your defined string, you are actually supressing the actual exception inside your catch block of execute() ? so provide us the actual exception to help more ?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception error it goes to ERROR result like it's suppose to when the user enters the incorrect login but it's just not returning SUCCESS when the user enters the correct login.  I'm not sure if it's related to my sql statement being wrong or if my prepared statement not being set properly?

Comment: Can you print the exception e.printStacktrace() inside your catch block of execute() ?

Comment: Things looks to be fine, but try logging the `username` and `password` in your action to verify if it matches with the database, or if it needs a trim. Also, print the stacktrace as requested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like.

```
 ............. 
 if(rs.next()) 
   {
         return SUCCESS; //the return atatement should be here. otherwise other statements should be evaluated.
   }
   else
   {
       addActionError("Invalid Username/Password"); 
       return ERROR;//here also
   }     
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return ERROR;
   }
```

Since you are having `where` clause in your query. So need of `while` and again `if`.

If you got any errors post your stack trace.

Comment: It seems to working now after your suggestions and got my original code to work after restarting my application server which I think wasn't updating properly. I think JBoss was the main problem that caused the issue but it seems to be working now.  Thanks for help.